# hide "more videos" within youtube iframe when stop video

Tags: iframe, youtube

How to hide the "more videos" section in Youtube iframes, when the user stops the video?

Example:

```
<iframe width="750" height="420" src="https://www.youtube/embed/cZnsLVArIt8?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

I cant find any solution [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 48):

If you have uBlock Origin ad-blocker installed, here's the static filter to remove that:

```
!YouTube embed pause overlay
youtube.com##.ytp-pause-overlay
```

Comment: "uBlock Rule:" isn't quite a complete answer.

Comment: For those wondering what to do with this snippet... You can't paste it into the element-picker dialog box. As described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61538266/665488), you have to go into the uBlock settings, go to "My filters", and add it there. Then click "Apply changes" and refresh the page.

Comment: I had precede this solution with `##.ytp-pause-overlay` in order for it to work.

Comment: Adding another domain: `www.youtube-nocookie.com##.ytp-pause-overlay` (this is used by DuckDuckGo)

Comment: For those who have Adblock Plus (ABP), Just paste this to Advanced->MY FILTER LIST-> +ADD . Remember to reload the page.

Comment: thank you very much for your question. Shame on you, YouTube! I have misclicked so many times, which does not add to your user's satisfaction.

Answer (score 19):

As per https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

> The behavior for the rel parameter is changing on or after September
>   25, 2018. The effect of the change is that **you will not be able to
>   disable related videos**. However, you will have the option of
>   specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from
>   the same channel as the video that was just played.
>
> To be more specific: Prior to the change, if the parameter's value is
>   set to 0, then the player does not show related videos. After the
>   change, if the rel parameter is set to 0, the player will show related
>   videos that are from the same channel as the video that was just
>   played.

It seems that it is youtubes intention to not give the ability to disable related videos functionality.

jquery way seems to not work either due to CORS, as would be css I guess.

```
$(".media-youtube-player").contents().find(".ytp-pause-overlay").remove();
```

causing blocked a frame with origin "xxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Not sure if there is a way doing this, unless youtube allows it again. Want to disable this too so any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Related Videos" was the list of videos that would display after an embedded video finished playing. The "More Videos" pause overlay was a new feature several years ago that (at least as of this writing) cannot be disabled in a way that is supported by YouTube.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Firefox with the Addon uBlock Origin.
Click on the logo of uBlock Origin and click on the settings icon, to `Open the dashboard`.

In the dashboard, go to the tab `My filters` and add this line:

```
youtube.com##.ytp-scroll-min.ytp-pause-overlay
```

Click `Apply changes`.
Now you won't see 'More video's while pausing a Youtube video.

[Source of this solution](https://archive.is/B9F6z)

Answer (score 4):

Reduced test case here:
https://codepen.io/jesserosenfield/full/VwZELye

Basically–– delay the pause and play functions using a custom button using `setTimeout` ... add showing/pausing/playing/paused classes to control CSS transitions of a "placeholder image".

Happy to explain in more detail if you need it, but the code pen should be pretty self explanatory!

**Javascript:**

```
        var player,
            $player,
            $playerWrap,
            $playerParent;

          // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
          //    after the API code downloads.
          function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            window.$player = $('#player'),
            window.$playerWrap = $('#player-wrap');
            window.$playerParent = $('#player-parent');

            window.player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '100%',
              width: '100%',
              videoId: jQuery('#player').attr('data-yt'),
              host: 'http://www.youtube.com',
              playerVars: {
                'enablejsapi' : 1,
                'playsinline': 1,
                'autoplay': 0,
                'controls': 0,
                'rel' : 0,
                'showinfo' : 0,
                'showsearch' : 0,
                'mute' : 1,
                'modestbranding' : 1,
                'disablekb' : 1,
                'loop' : 1,
                'origin': window.location.href
              },
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
          }

          function playClasses($el) {
                $el.addClass('playing').removeClass('paused showing');
          };

          function pauseClasses($el) {
                $el.removeClass('playing pausing').addClass('paused');
          };

          // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
          function onPlayerReady(event) {

            (function($) {
                window.$playerWrap = $('#player-wrap');
                window.$playerParent = $('#player-parent');
                window.$playerWrap.on('click', function(){

                    var player = window.player,
                        $me = $(this);


                    if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
                        window.$playerParent.removeClass('playing').addClass('pausing');

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            player.pauseVideo();                
                        }, 350);
                    } else {
                        window.$playerParent.addClass('showing');
                        player.playVideo();             
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
          };



          // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
          //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
          //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
          var done = false;

          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

            var thedata = event.data;
            //Ended
            if (thedata === 0) {
                window.player.playVideo(); 
                window.player.seekTo(1); 
            }

            // Playing
            if (thedata === 1) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    playClasses(window.$playerParent);      
                }, 450);
            }

            // Paused
            if(thedata === 2) {
                pauseClasses(window.$playerParent);
            }
          }
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="player-parent">
          <div id="player-wrap" class="pr">
            <div class="player-ph--color">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="player-ph"></div>

            <div id="player" data-yt="CjB_oVeq8Lo"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
          var tag = document.createElement('script');

          tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        </script>
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```
        .player-ph{
          width: 50%;
          height: 100%;
          position: relative;
          background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503714964235-8954a5249c00?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80);
          background-size: cover;
             mix-blend-mode: multiply;
            filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
            filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */;
        }

        #player-wrap {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
          position: relative;
        }

        .player-ph,
        .player-ph--color,
        #player {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }

        #player {
          z-index: 5;
          pointer-events: none;
          opacity: 0
        }

        .player-ph--color {
          background: red;
        }

        .player-ph--color:after {
            content: "▶️";
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                height: 300px;
            font-size: 150px;
            color: #fff;
                opacity: .5;
                display: block;
                z-index: 2 
          }

        #player {
          transition: opacity .325s ease-out;
        }

        .player-ph--color:after {
          transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
        }

        #player-parent {
            &.pausing,
            &.paused {
                #player {
                    opacity: 0  
                }
            }

          &.playing,
            &.showing {
            .player-ph--color:after {
              opacity: 0
            }
            }

            &.playing #player {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
```

Comment: Great method! Never knew this trick:)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this way

1. using a YouTube user with no public videos available
2. uploading an `unlisted` video
3. added "rel=0" in the src video url of the iframe

See the example below

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HAxjVEiBvCA?rel=0"></iframe>
```

P.S.: I might delete the video example in future, so just change id video and be sure there are no public visibility video available in the account who generated the iframe

Answer (score -3):

You just need to remove "rel=0" from the Iframe.

Comment: That is impossible according to the documentation
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls