# how can I hide the "more videos" in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

i'm using the youtube js api.
when I stop the video, the section "more videos" appears, Can i hide it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeyLX.png)

Comment: I would flag as a duplicate because of this post but the user never accepted the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887444/hide-more-videos-within-youtube-iframe-when-stop-video. Also very similar to this one, but the accepted answer is out of date (2nd answer is same information as the first link I posted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887444/hide-more-videos-within-youtube-iframe-when-stop-video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide "more videos" within youtube iframe when stop video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887444/hide-more-videos-within-youtube-iframe-when-stop-video)